# How count line by minutes in big log file?

Tags: bash

Pls Help!
I`m have such log file:

```
[AJPRqu92] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,872 INFO   rervice -  signer.setObject(SiocumntObject.getSgnedocumetbect(xmDoctr.getBytes("UTF-8")));, 0 .
[AJPeqe2] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,872 INFO   r.ervice -  signatureFactory.newSignedDocumentSerializer(), 0 .
[AJPR90] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   roController - <evc:1; cat:4>       . {'ip': 0000, 'size(64)': 1208 }
[AJPReq] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   re -  signer.getSignedDocument(), 93 .
[AJPequesHaHandlr-10] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   rce -   SignatureFactory, 0 .
[AJPequetHandler-RM0] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   ctoService -   UnificationFactory, 0 .
[AuesHandlr-R0] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   ua-   ptoPiderParams, CryptoProvider, 0 .
[AetHander-Rler-2] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   u.c.tse.scypservices.CryptoService -  signer.getSignedDocument(), 93 .
[AJPRequer-RMIallHad-8] 2019-11-04 00:01:31,965 INFO   ru.es.CrSece -  serializer.serialize(sineDocment, bytOtputStream), 0 .
```

I need to count how many lines per minutes each days generated, example:

```
2019-11-04 00:01 - 9
2019-11-04 00:02 - 10
2019-11-05 10:21 - 3
```

How can I do it using bash?

Comment: 1. extract the date with time without seconds from the file. You can use `cut` to extract the fields and then again `cut` to remove seconds, or just match it all with regex  with `sed`. 2. Use `sort | uniq -c` to count the duplicates (maybe the file is sorted, then dont sort). After counting, you can again use ex. `sed` to achieve your format. See [man cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) [man sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) [man uniq](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) and [sed introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: @KamilCuk This is the correct answer. Why don't you post is as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk.

Something like:

```
awk -F"[ :]" '{++a[$2" "$3":"$4]}END{for (item in a){print item, a[item]}}'
```

This will

1. Split each line by space or colon `-F"[ :]"`
2. For each line in an array called `a`, increment the value for a key that is made up from the datetime: `{++a[$2" "$3":"$4]}`
3. Once the file is processed it will iterate the array and print the key(datetime) and value(count) `END{for (item in a){print item, a[item]}}`

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I would extract all the dates first and then use a `for` loop to count the entries with the same date.

```
 dates=`cat ~/myLogFile.log | cut -f2 -d" " | uniq`
 for f in $dates ; do value=`grep $f ~/myLogFile.log  | wc -l`; echo "$f - $value" ; done

2019-11-04 - 9
2019-11-05 - 1
```

If you want the minutes, you can change the `cut` statement based on your log

```
dates=`cat ~/myLogFile.log | cut -f2-3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"," | uniq
```